# Use Quarter in GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

I am trying to use Quarter inside date part in my query with Group By but it isn't working for me.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    Id, Name,
    Quarter1 = (SELECT COUNT(TS.Id) FROM TS WHERE TS.Status = STATUS.StatusId GROUP BY DATEPART(QUARTER,TS.EndDate)),
    Quarter2 = (SELECT COUNT(TS.Id) FROM TS WHERE TS.Status = STATUS.StatusId  GROUP BY DATEPART(QUARTER,TS.EndDate)),
    Quarter3 = (SELECT COUNT(TS.Id) FROM TS WHERE TS.Status = STATUS.StatusId GROUP BY DATEPART(QUARTER,TS.EndDate)),
    Quarter4 = (SELECT COUNT(TS.Id) FROM TS WHERE TS.Status = STATUS.StatusId GROUP BY DATEPART(QUARTER,TS.EndDate))
FROM 
    TS 
INNER JOIN 
    STATUS ON TS.Status = STATUS.StatusId
GROUP BY 
    Id, Name
```

I need to by my data result like in example

```
Id   Name    Quarter1 Quarter2 Quarter3 Quarter4
---- ----    -------- -------- -------- --------
1    STATUS1    1       2           3       4
2    STATUS2    4       12          66      80
3    STATUS3    5       10          23      9
4    STATUS4    9       7           90      99
5    STATUS5    20      5           88      22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need inner queries - just `count` a conditional expression:

```sql
SELECT     Id,
           Name,
           Quarter1 = COUNT(CASE DATEPART(QUARTER, TS.EndDate) WHEN 1 THEN 1 END),
           Quarter2 = COUNT(CASE DATEPART(QUARTER, TS.EndDate) WHEN 2 THEN 1 END),
           Quarter3 = COUNT(CASE DATEPART(QUARTER, TS.EndDate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 END),
           Quarter4 = COUNT(CASE DATEPART(QUARTER, TS.EndDate) WHEN 4 THEN 1 END)
FROM       TS
INNER JOIN STATUS ON TS.Status = STATUS.StatusId
GROUP BY   Id, Name
```